# Abstracting canvas methods causes elements to be drawn on their own pages?

Tags: python, python-3.x, reportlab

I am trying to refactor a script that generates several four page pdfs and abstract a very long >400 line script into several methods. I have methods that draw each footer and create each of the four pages. The problem is that when I call `doc.addPageTemplates()` only works when given a single template. If I try to add more than one it creates a separate page for each element.

For example, this method generates the second page:

```
def page_two():

f_title = Frame(width - doc.rightMargin - graph_width + 0.2 * inch,
                     doc.bottomMargin + footer_height + 7,
                     graph_width, cap_height,
                     leftPadding=0, rightPadding=0,
                     topPadding=0, bottomPadding=0,
                     id='title')

f_graph = Frame(width - doc.rightMargin - graph_width,
                     doc.bottomMargin + footer_height,
                     graph_width, cap_height,
                     leftPadding=0, rightPadding=0,
                     topPadding=0, bottomPadding=0,
                     id='graph')

post_header_space = 3
elements.append(Paragraph("LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET"
                          , styles['body_heading']))
elements.append(Spacer(1, post_header_space))
yld_para = "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit"
elements.append(Paragraph(yld_para
                          , styles['body_text']))
elements.append(FrameBreak())

elements.append(Spacer(1, 40))

elements.append(Paragraph("%s YLDs by cause and age 2010" % country_name
                          , styles['fig_cap']))
elements.append(FrameBreak())
elements.append(Paragraph("LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET"
                          , styles['body_heading']))
elements.append(Spacer(1, post_header_space))


elements.append(FrameBreak())
elements.append(Spacer(1, 10))

elements.append(FrameBreak())

elements.append(PageBreak())
return PageTemplate(id='SecondPage', frames=[f_title, f_graph], onPage=foot_dash_2)
```

and this generates its footer:

```
def foot_dash_2(canvas, doc):
    arrow_scale = 1.0
    canvas.translate(-.23 * inch, -9.9 * inch)
    canvas.scale(arrow_scale, arrow_scale)
    canvas.restoreState()
    canvas.scale(arrow_scale, arrow_scale)

    canvas.restoreState()
    arrow_scale = 0.55
    canvas.translate(doc.leftMargin + 126.0 + 7.5 * inch, 31.0 - 0.2 * inch)
    canvas.scale(arrow_scale, arrow_scale)
    canvas.rotate(90)

    canvas.restoreState()
    canvas.saveState()
    canvas.setLineWidth(0.4)
    canvas.setDash(0.4, 5)
    line_height = 329.8 + 72.0 + dash_buffer / 2

    canvas.line(doc.leftMargin, line_height, width - doc.rightMargin, line_height)
    canvas.restoreState()

    canvas.saveState()

    canvas.setFont('Helvetica', 22)
    canvas.setFillColorCMYK(81 / 100.0, 45 / 100.0, 53 / 100.0, 23 / 100.0)  # choose fill colour
    canvas.rect(0, doc.bottomMargin - 3, width, 15, fill=1, stroke=0)
    left_foot = Paragraph("http://www.example.cp,",
                          styles['left_footer_1'])
    w, h = left_foot.wrap(doc.width, doc.bottomMargin)
    left_foot.drawOn(canvas, doc.leftMargin, doc.bottomMargin - foot_displace)
    right_foot = Paragraph(" %s | Text | page %d" % (country_name, 2),
                           styles['right_footer_1'])
    w, h = right_foot.wrap(doc.width, doc.bottomMargin)
    right_foot.drawOn(canvas, doc.rightMargin, doc.bottomMargin - foot_displace)
    canvas.restoreState()
    # Y axis label
    canvas.saveState()
    canvas.setFont('OpenSans', 7)
    canvas.setFillColorRGB(0, 0, 0, 1)
    canvas.rotate(90)
    canvas.drawString(2 * inch, -3.2 * inch, "Percent change 1990-2010")
    canvas.restoreState()
```

As you can see the `page_two()` method adds elements to an elements list and returns a PageTemplate object.

I generate the PDF like this:

```
doc.addPageTemplates([page_two()])
doc.build(elements)
```

This works. However, if I want to add multiple page templates, the only correct page is the first one and then reportlab generates a page for every individual element:

```
doc.addPageTemplates([page_one(), page_two(), page_three(), page_four()])
doc.build(elements)
```

How can I stop this from happening and generate complete pages? All the other page methods and footer methods are variations of the ones posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not clear in the reportlab docs, but if when using simple doc template you need to add a NextPageTemplate in order to start new Page Object to contain all frames. So in this case you would just add `elements.append(NextPageTemplate('SecondPage'))` to the end of the method that generates the first page.